# XSLT Error is coming even when the 'when' is condition is false

Tags: xslt

I have a piece of code in my XSLT and it has some condition as follows:

```
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="$columns = 3 and $contents = 'probate-checklist'">
         <div class="intro-group">
          <div class="main container" id="main_content">

            <section class="services-intro">
              <div class="main-pane">
                <xsl:call-template name="gzintro"/>
              </div>

            </section>
          </div>
        </div> 
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
```

When the condition is absolutely fail, but, still, i am getting an error as there is no such template named 'gzintro'. Here, my concern is, this 'WHEN' is failed, then, how can it go into the when section coding. Pls anyone let me understand this

Comment: sure this is execution error and not xslt compilation error?

Comment: I am getting this error when i am executing this with my relevant input xml file.

Comment: That probably means your XSLT is being compiled/processed when you execute it. An XSLT that calls a non-existant template is invalid, even if that part of the XSLT never executed.